# SAS - Need to stop code if a column has a value not in a list

Tags: macros, sas

I have a variable called `CLIENT_ID`. It is used to loop through a bunch of code. The problem is the macro is looking for a specific list of clients like so:

```
%stuff(CLIENTX)
%stuff(CLIENTA)
```

and so on. So if a new client appears in the data (say `CLIENTY`), that client isn't included in the output.

I would like to either:

1. have the code check against a list of existing clients and stop if a new client is found, outputting the name of that client so the macro can be updated manually
2. have the code check for new clients and then automatically add them to the macro list

I know how to compare to find the new client id, it's just the stopping the code or updating the code if there is a new client that I am struggling with. Probably the second one is not possible? But I'm hoping there is at least some way to resolve this issue.

I will fully admit I am not an expert in macros.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing the program. Can you post a small example of what it is doing using a few data points?

Comment: We've got a handful of questions with a similar nature, search "data-driven programming SAS".

Comment: @StuSztukowski - I think what Joe has will work. But I'm always open to more suggestions. Basically there is a main dataset which has every client with all their accounts (could be millions) and a bunch of other information. The macro today is using the client to loop through and pull some of those fields down then append all the data together. The main dataset is so large, that's why we do this. But we get new clients without notice and so our hardcoded macro misses them. I am not entirely sure how to get examples in here though.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is call your macro from your data, not from written code.

So instead of

```
%yourMacro(clientX)
%yourMacro(clientY)
```

You do:

```
proc sql;
  select distinct cats('%yourMacro(',clientID,')')
    into :macro_call_list separated by ' '
    from your_Data
  ;
quit;

&macro_call_list.;
```

You either direct `your_data` to the main dataset, if that's what you have, or to a list of valid clients if you have that maintained in a separate file (such as a client location crosswalk or somesuch).  Whatever would have the most current data.  Adding `distinct` to the query guarantees you just one call per `clientID`.  Then `&macro_call_list` contains all of those `%yourMacro(clientX)` etc. calls, and just putting that reference in open code calls it.

Comment: I tested it on a small list and it worked. I'm testing it on the whole main file right now, which is nearly a billion records. It's been running but I think it will work. I'd rather have longer run time than manually updating all the time. Thanks!